# Glassfish - retrieve a pdf file from server

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

Using servlet, i have to stored a pdf file in Root directory (glass fish server)

```
 PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
 pdfMerger.addSources(sources);
 String pdfFileName = "pdf-test100.pdf";
 String contextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
  pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName(contextPath+pdfFileName);
  pdfMerger.mergeDocuments();
```

File stored in the below location

```
D:\NetBeansProjects\pdfapp\build\web\pdf-test100.pdf
```

My next step i want to download the file from the above path 
jsp page i'm creating an hyperlink once click file downloaded from the above path.

I'm beginner level in servlet and server so please suggest me how to proceed the download action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `servlet API` tutorial. Servlet API provide same behavior for `Glassfish` or any other Application Container. E.g. [this tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        performTask(request, response);
}   
private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        String pdfFileName = "pdf-test100.pdf";
        String contextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
        File pdfFile = new File(contextPath + pdfFileName);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
        response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
}
```

Put your `pdf-test100.pdf` file into `WEB-INF` directory.